# Google Column Chart - Show different color for each column

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-api, google-visualization

**Snippet**

```
        google.load("visualization", "1", {packages: ["corechart", "bar"]});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);

        function drawStuff() {

            var timesheetRes = ["Resouce 1","Resouce 2","Resouce 3","Resouce 4","Resouce 5"];
            var timesheetWeek = ["Week 1","Week 2","Week 3","Week 4","Week 5"];
            var timesheetHours = [45,40,40,0,0];

            var dataArray = [['Resources', 'Week', 'Hours']];
            for (var n = 0; n < timesheetHours.length; n++) {
                dataArray.push([timesheetRes[n], timesheetWeek[n], timesheetHours[n]]);
            }
            var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArray);

            var color = <?php echo $json_color_str ?>;
            var color_count = <?php echo $color_count ?>;

            for (var i = 0; i < color_count; i++) {

            var color_str = color[i];

            var options = {
            width: 700,
            height: 350,
            legend: {position: 'none'},
            bar: {groupWidth: '50%'},
            isStacked: true,
            tooltip: {trigger: 'none'},
            colors: color_str, //being passed in array format for each bar
            hAxis: {title: "Resource(s)",
                titleTextStyle: {color: '#e91e63', bold: 1, fontSize: 14}},
            vAxis: {title: "Week(s)",
                ticks: weekAxis(),
                gridlineColor: 'transparent',
                titleTextStyle: {color: '#F4B400', bold: 1, fontSize: 14}
            }
        };

            var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("top_x_div"));
            chart.draw(data, options);
    }



}

function weekAxis() {

    var ticks = new Array();
    var week_count = <?php echo $week_no ?>; //count number of weeks

    for (i = 1; i <= week_count; i++) {
        var tick_str = {};
        tick_str['v'] = (week_count * i);
        tick_str['f'] = 'Week ' + i;
        ticks.push(tick_str);
    }
    return ticks;

}


    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script> 
    <div id="top_x_div"></div>
```

**Current Output**

[image]

**Expected Output**

[image]

where `Week(s)` will be displayed on **vAxis** while `Resource(s)` will be displayed on **hAxis**. Here I have changed `hAxis` and `vAxis` values to display Weeks and
    Resources respectively and show fix `4/5/6` chart sections considering number of `weeks` in a month.

Tried looping `options` by passing color array for each bar, but it only takes the last array passed and thus displays same color for each and its columns.

- How can I change color of chart columns based on color string
  passed as shown in expected output image ?

Or is it possible using jQuery ?

Comment: insted of setting the colors on options, you should try to set them on each bar, var dataArray = [['Resources', 'Week', 'Hours',{ role: 'style' }]];
and then :  dataArray.push([timesheetRes[n], timesheetWeek[n], timesheetHours[n], 'color: #76A7FA']); and put the color you want instead of   #76A7FA

Comment: @juvian, thanks for responding. But I need to apply different color to each bar column. Will the above work for different bar color or column color in each bar ?

Comment: Mmm you are right, doens't seem to be an easy way. Could you make a fiddle with the current output chart? You code is missing some php variables. Can try playing with the options but need to try it on something

Comment: @juvian, not sure if this fiddle would work - http://jsfiddle.net/Qquse/1548/

Comment: In my code, `color_str ` is looped for each bar column to apply relevant color. Thought looping `options` would work, but some how it only takes the last `color_str` being passed and overrides which applies to each bar columns

Comment: You can only create 1 options object, in this code you are creating 8 charts, each one overriding the previous one, all with same config but the color, so yeah, it has the color of the last value in color

Comment: @juvian so what could be the possible solutions? I completely agree with what you say but is this problem really solvable ?

Comment: Haven´t really used google charts in more than a year, so kind of lost my touch :(. Maybe you can use this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-visualization-api/column$20chart$20set$20bar$20color/google-visualization-api/NMb4taYw6rw/_hwhKRZP924J. But not sure if it works for stacked values as you want